# Random forest regression- force to use more than 20% of possible variables

Tags: python, optimization, random-forest

I'm building model with about 30 features. I know the best fit would be if RF (regression) would use many of them (more than 20%) in similar proportions (in meaning model.feature_importances_ would be high for many of them).  I performed some optimization using different n_estimators,max_depth, leaf_nodes and so on. I did't found the parameter of RF that forces using many features. Of course I can limit usage of them from top, but how from bottom?

Comment: Is your aim to decide how many features should be considered at each split?

Answer (score 1):

Look into this:
https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blackbox/permutation_importance.html

The limiting from the bottom doesn't make a lot of sense.
During fit, you can use n_features parameter.